# How to find the least degree of the polynomial satisfying the given conditions?

Tags: polynomials

let $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + ....+a_nx^n. If\; p(-2) = -15, \ p(1) = 9, \ p(-1) =  1,\ p(0) = 7, \ p(2) = 13\; and\; p(3) = 25$ then the smallest possible value of $n$.

what I tried is that 
$p(0) = 7\,, a_0 = 7$, $p(1) = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 +.....+a_n = 9$. (1)

$p(-1) = a_0 - a_1 + a_2..... = 1$. (2)

$p(2) = a_0 + 2a_1 + 4a_2 + ..... = 13$.(3)

$p(-2) = a_0 - 2a_1 + 4a_2.... = -15$. (4)

by adding (1) and (2) we get $p(1) + p(-1) = 2[a_0 + a_2 +...] = 10$.

and $p(2) + p(-2) = 2[a_0 + 4a_2 +...] = -2$

is there any way to proceed from here?

Comment: Can't prove it, but I have $n = 3$ with the polynomial $x^3-2x^2+3x+7$

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematics SE Biswa Prakash.It is very helpful to know what trials and errors you have made. This way we can better assess your capabilities and act accordingly. Ergo "What have you tried?"If you don't do so, most probably questions get closed here, I.e. no new answers can be added. Since you are new user, I am not voting to close this question. But be sure to add your effort unless this question will be closed later.

Comment: By brute force: there are $6$ conditions, so the interpolating polynomial would have degree at most $5\,$. Write down the system of equations (which simplifies quickly) and solve for the coefficients. Turns out that the highest power with a non-zero coefficient is the $3^{rd}\,$, and the solution is the already posted cubic.

Comment: P.S. After the latest edit: see my previous comment, let $n=5\,$, and solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with
$$-15,1,7,9,13,25$$
(By the way, why is your $p(1)$ out of sequence?)

Take differences once:
$$16,6,2,4,12$$

Take differences twice:
$$-10,-4,2,8$$

Take differences a third time:
$$6,6,6$$

The final sequence is constant, i.e. a polynomial of degree $0$. Working backwards, the original sequence is a polynomial of degree $3$.

Comment: can you please elaborate how this method works

Comment: @biswaprakashmishra: if $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $q$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, where $q(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)$. This is easy to show $-$ just look at the leading term.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lagrange interpolation formula,so you can get a polynomial satisfying the given conditions, as for the smallest degree,maybe the Chinese Remainder theorem is useful.

Comment: Can you elaborate

Comment: On this problem,you can do it explicitly,p(x)=xg(x)+7,g(x) satisfies 5 conditions,requiring deg(g) smallest. g(x)=q(x)(x+1)+a,q(x) 4 conditions with smallest degree,do this procedures again,you can get the polynomial as desired.

Answer (score 0):

As John Lou mentions, $p(x)=x^3-2x^2+3x+7$ satisfies all the equalities. A polynomial of degree two couldn't, because the slopes cannot decrease and then increase again. Or, even easier, a parabola has constant convexity, while the set of points given imply concave on $(-2,0)$ and convex on $(1,3)$.